# Google DataStream won't start with no error

Tags: google-datastream

Trying to set up a datastream between Cloud SQL (postgres) and BigQuery using this quickstart -> https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/quickstart-replication-to-bigquery

Connection profiles successfully created and tests successful.  Stream created successfully but won't start.  Only error is the attached screenshot which states:  Failed to start Survey Domain Stream The attempted action failed, please try again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HVU9.png)

Stream was supposed to start.  No errors were displayed on any of the screens.  Not sure how to even troubleshoot.